# Html `TextArea` attribute `rows` doesn't work correctly

Tags: html, textarea

For some reason, I need to use my "textarea" input element just like the "text" type input element.
I tried to achieve it using the following code.

```
<textarea style="{resize: none; height:25px}" name="myTextArea" rows="1">
```

But, the cursor in the textarea can go 1 row down when I click at the bottom of the textarea.
Simply, I just want to make this textarea similar to a simple text box (i.e using input tag).

Please help if any idea.

Comment: Why aren't you using a regular text input tag?

Comment: because i need to add text to the textbox from the php script.
i saw that it is possible with text area

Comment: @SarimJavaidKhan, we can intergrate php into almost any html element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference between a textarea and an input is that a textarea can have several lines. So that a textarea works like an input, it's necessary not be able to add lines.

I think you have to use Javascript to do this. So look the following code :

```
<textarea style="resize: none; height:25px" name="myTextArea" rows="1"></textarea>
<script>
    document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0].onkeydown = function(e){
        if (e.which == 13){
            return false
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: itz not my requirement to use java script sir.
I dont know why people are downgrading my question.
may be the question is not clear to them.

Comment: @SarimJavaidKhan, the question is not up to grade!

Comment: @MohammadAreebSiddiqui his question was fine. the answer does not address the question